# Aurelia not outputting attribute with string interpolation in repeat

Tags: aurelia

Is there any reason why a repeat.for binding would remove attributes from elements inside the repeater?

```
<div repeat.for="i of model.someArray.length">
    <label>Some Array - Index ${i + 1}</label>
    <input value.bind="model.someArray[i]" some-custom-attribute="someArray[${i}]"/>
</div>
```

and that `some-custom-attribute` is not being output within the repeat, but if I were to remove the string interpolation within there then it outputs fine.

== Edit ==

I have put it in a comment but just to make sure everyone is on the same page, ideally this is the output I expect:

`<input value.bind="model.someArray[i]" some-custom-attribute="someArray[0]"/>`

The `some-custom-attribute` is not an aurelia attribute, its pure HTML that a 3rd party JS library uses, so the goal here is to get the textual value of the index into the textual attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

`model.someArray.length` is a number, not an array. You need to iterate over the array. If you do need the current index, the repeater provides the `$index` property for you to use.

Your code should look like this:

```html
<div repeat.for="item of model.someArray">
    <label>Some Array - Index ${$index + 1}</label>
    <input value.bind="item" some-custom-attribute.bind="item"/>
</div>
```

To answer your original question, doing `some-custom-attribute="model.someArray[${i}]"` makes Aurelia think you are trying to pass a string value to the custom attribute. You can see that in the following gist: https://gist.run/?id=eed8ac8623ff4749aa5bb93c82a7b1fb I've created a custom element that just pushes whatever value it is given in to an element on the page. ***Note!!! Don't ever do what I'm doing here!*** I just did this this way so you wouldn't have to open the js console. To actually get a value passed in, you would need to use `some-custom-attribute.bind="item"` or (to do things how you are doing things, `some-custom-attribute.bind="someArray[i]"`

Comment: Even though this is not my question, I learned about the `$index` property.  Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: Yeah, I actually learned that iterating on a number works. I didn't know that. That being said, the way i showed is how you should accomplish this. I'll look in to why the custom attribute doesn't work, since basically you're passing a string to it in your code.

Comment: Just to confirm this is not a custom aurelia attribute, its just a html attribute that a 3rd party JS library uses, I just want to pass it the value `someArray[0]` with 0 being replaced by the current index, I do not want to pass in the actual element in there, if $index can be used instead of `i` I can use that but I am basically not wanting aurelia to do anything here other than make the `some-custom-attribute` value be the text `someArray[0]`. Also the repeat does work for the other parts as expected, so it repeats `n` times, but I agree it would look better being a foreach style thing.